# magic_quotes_runtime Usage and reason of deprecation

Tags: php

I have code which uses set_magic_quotes_runtime() and magic_quotes_runtime().

I just noticed they have been deprecated.

Are there any Important Security problems with these functions? Or can I use them without problems on php version 5.3 or later?

Why are they deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason has to do what it's been used for: ecaping values in SQL statements. The problem is that the escaping method in magic_quotes is not correct for it's mostly used target: MySQL. This can lead to security holes.

In addition to that, it enforces bad programming practices. Anyone writing PHP code would have to check for the current php.ini value and undo the magic quoting to make sure code works consistently where magic quotes is either on or off.

The feature was deprecated and won't actually work anymore.

If you're looking to properly escape your queries, look into MySQLi or PDO's Prepared Statements.

**Edit** Turns out there's even a wikipedia page! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_quotes

Comment: thanks, could you mention an example where it fails to escape a value?

Comment: @Ara: that's too late for the contents of $_GET and $_POST to change. Test first, then ask :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't manage every possibility to put a quote in a string.

Comment: could you mention an example where it fails?

Comment: This will help you: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string